# Show that the sphere, S, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I am trying to show that the sphere $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not homeomorphic.I understand that you can't 'compress' a 3D shape into a 2D plane but I don't know how I would express this formally.

$S^2 = \{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$

As always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you get to infinity on R? But can you do the same on a sphere? I'm terrible at formalising the idea, though that might get you started.

Comment: One is compact another one is not.

Comment: @Nij you can say that the one-point compactification of the plane is the sphere. This sort of captures your intuition (possibly).

Comment: Yes, that's what I was aiming at (I didn't want to go through "point at infinity" in case that required further explanation for OP).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homeomorphism will preserve any "topological" property of spaces - in particular, $S^2$ is compact and $\mathbb R^2$ is not, so they can't be homeomorphic.

In fact, the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact, so there is not even a surjective continuous map $S^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\;f:S^2\to\Bbb R^2\;$ is a homeomorphism then $\;f:S^2\setminus\{x_0\}\to\Bbb R\setminus\{f(x_0)\}\;$ also is, yet the sphere minus any point is simply connected whereas the plane minus any point isn't.

Or as above but with "contractible" instead of simply connected.

Comment: and it should be noted that this argument proves the stronger claim that the two spaces are not even homotopic.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Thank you. I agree with you, yet Joshua's answer is way simpler.

Comment: @DonAntonio Why does this imply that the same map but with $x_0$ taken out of $S^2$ is still homeomorphic?

Answer (score 0):

If they were homeomorphic, then they have the same homotopy groups $\pi_k$ for every $k\ge0$. Notice that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible whereas $S^2$ is not. In particular $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is trivial whereas $\pi_2(S^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$. So they are not homeomorphic.